# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate issue

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Have an issue with getting access to a button that is embedded in a 
DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate.    The button is created fine and can attach an event to the button.  All works well, except when attempting to get access from the code behind,  Ex:btnbutton.IsEnabled = false;  Returns an error and said the object does not exist.    I have tested this with various version of .NET up to 4.5 and get the same results,  btnButton does not exist.

I have done this same with a ListView object and it works fine.

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgTest1" ItemsSource="{Binding} AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <Button Name="btnButton" Content="One Button" WinWidth="100"></Button>
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:  btnButton.IsEnabled = false;
Is there a way to gain access to a button in a DataGrid Template Header?

Comment: You cant access this button like that because this button might not even exist - it's just a model. If You want to get it, You need to use VisualTreeHelper or You can bind this Button.Tag to some property and implement INotifyPropertChanged on this.

Comment: Have you tried the old GetChildControl method of getting wpf controls?

Comment: Enabling/Disabling buttons from code while they are in a template is a bad approach. Use triggers for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
var aButton = templateName.ChildrenOfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault( b => b.Name == "btnButton" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access template control like that, you need to apply template and then find them

You need to call apply template first on DataGrid header and then

```
var button = dgTest1.template.findname("btnButton", dgTest1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way here would be to bind your button to a property on the view model:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" Content="One Button"/>
```

or to a command (you can implement your own command, create a property IsEnabled in it, and return this property's value from the CanExecute() method). Let me know if you need more details here.